# Changing image sizes proportionally using CSS

Tags: html, css, gallery, lightbox

I have been trying for a couple of days now to configure my thumbnail gallery so all the images appear the same height and width. However, when I change the CSS code to,

```css
max-height: 150px;
max-width: 200px;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
```

I get images that are all the same size, but the aspect ratio is stretched, ruining the images. Is there not a way to resize the image container and not the image instead? Allowing me to keep the aspect ratio, but resize the image still. (I don’t mind if I cut off some of the image.)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

This is a known problem with CSS resizing. Unless all images have the same proportion, you have no way to do this via CSS.

The best approach would be to have a container, and resize one of the dimensions (always the same) of the images. In my example I resized the width.

If the container has a specified dimension (in my example the width), when telling the image to have the width at 100%, it will make it the full width of the container. The `auto` at the height will make the image have the height proportional to the new width.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="something.png" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <img src="something2.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}

/* Resize images */
.container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 51):

You need to fix one side (for example, height) and set the other to `auto`.

For example,

```
 height: 120px;
 width: auto;
```

That would scale the image based on one side only. If you find cropping the image acceptable, you can just set

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent element, which would crop out anything that would otherwise exceed its size.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still gives me images that are all different sizes and shapes i want the gallery to be uniform like so,   [] [] [] [] not like [] [] [  ] [  ] []

Comment: use a combination of both the above: set height to a number (with auto width to keep scale), and limit the parent to a specific width with `overflow: hidden` to crop the excess

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `object-fit` CSS 3 property. Something like:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    .holder {
      display: inline;
    }
    .holder img {
      max-height: 200px;
      max-width: 200px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='holder'>
    <img src='meld.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='holder'>
    <img src='twiddla.png'>
  </div>
  <div class='holder'>
    <img src='meld.png'>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It is not exactly your answer, though, because it doesn't stretch the container. But it behaves like the gallery and you can keep styling the `img` itself.

Another drawback of this solution is still a poor support of the CSS 3 property. More details are available here: [CSS 3 Object-fit Polyfill](http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/css3-object-fit-polyfill/). A jQuery solution can be found there as well.

Comment: This is kinda odd to answer with a property that is only supported in opera atm?! http://caniuse.com/object-fit

Comment: I see your point, @Simon, thank you. I mentioned I have no idea if the property will be supported everywhere, but _even if it will not_, we can use it as a starting point to google for _alternatives_ which replace it. Another reason to post is that the answer would stay for some time while browsers are getting better with every day, so I answered targeting _this near future_ as well.

Comment: Coming to this page several years later I was happy to find this 'future' answer!

Answer (score 9):

To make images adjustable/flexible you could use this:

```
/* fit images to container */
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put it as a background on your holder e.g.

```
<div style="background:url(path/to/image/myimage.jpg) center center; width:120px; height 120px;">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

This will center your image inside a 120x120 div chopping off any excess of the image

Answer (score 6):

```css
transform: scale(0.5);
```

---

#### Example:

```html
<div>Normal</div>
<div class="scaled">Scaled</div>
```

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.scaled {
  transform: scale(0.7); /* Equal to scaleX(0.7) scaleY(0.7) */
  background-color: pink;
}
```

See [scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to stretch the image, fit it into a div container without overflow and center it by adjusting its margin if needed.

1. **The image will not get cropped**
2. **The aspect ratio will also remain the same.**

#### HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <div id="container">
      <img src="#" alt="something">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <img src="#" alt="something">
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <img src="#" alt="something">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div#container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 4px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This helps me to make the image 150% with ease.

```
.img-popup img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this should be more as a last resort, but you could simply do math. For example, lets say that you have an image with a width of 595 and height of 300. You would create a unit rate by doing 300/595 = 0.504. Then, you would plug in a width that you would like to change the image to (1000px). 1000 x 0.504 = 504. This means that the height of the image should be 504 if the width is 1000 if you want to keep it proportional.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the aspect ratio, you can use padding-bottom with percentage to set the height depending on the width of the diff.

```
<div>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 33%;">
      I have 33% height of my parents width
   </div>
</div>
```