# I am unable to customize the size of my picture in css.

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, width

I am trying to make the picture 100% but it wont work.

Code:

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Intro Section -->
<div class="headerimg"
     ><img src="pix/stockvault-city-skyline-at-sunset-113039.jpg">
</div>
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#about" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.headerimg {
width: 50%;
height: 100px; }
```

It would be very helpful if anyone can help. I am usually able to do it but for some reason I am unable to do it this time. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685666/changing-image-sizes-proportionally-using-css

Answer (score 1):

Just change CSS to:

```
    .headerimg
    {
     width: 50%;
     height: 100px; 
    }

  img {
     width: 100%;
   }
```

It will make Image `100%` in width.

look this : http://jsfiddle.net/cadh3vv9/

Answer (score 0):

try the follow code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Intro Section -->
<div class="headerimg"
     ><img style="width=50%" src="pix/stockvault-city-skyline-at-sunset-113039.jpg">
</div>
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#about" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">Tell Me More</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

I styled the image to 50% width you also want it to be 100 px height well thats wrong,  its something like telling the browser show a pic of a roadkilled dog, you must define what you preffer, width or height because image resize uses one of these values to resize correct