# How to resize a png image to fit in a div?

Tags: javascript, css, image, reactjs

I am trying to resize a **PNG** image to fit in a **div**

This the div where I'd like to fit it in:
[image]

But this is how it looks like:

[image]

I tried to solve it by this [Changing image sizes proportionally using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685666/changing-image-sizes-proportionally-using-css) but no change was noticed.

Here's the code snippet:

```
 <div className="Card-header">
                {this.props.roadmapID}
                <label className="Card-header-status">{this.props.technology.toString().replace(/,/g , " ")}</label>
                <label>{this.props.category}</label>
                <img src="images/dark_chat.png"></img>
                <CardStatus
                    status = {this.props.status}
                    onClickStatus = {this.props.onClickStatus}
                />
            </div>
```

Comment: can you share your code too

Comment: If the div is wrapped around the img tag, than you just can set `div img { width: 100% }` in your CSS

Comment: I posted you some code, which should solve your problem. :) The problem with `div img { width: 100% }` is, that does this with all images in every div you use with this stylesheet, because it is not separated through an `id` or `class`.

Comment: please mark a answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 5):

```
div.Card-header > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use in your Stylesheet

```
 .Card-header {
        width: XYpx;
        height: XYpx;
    }
```

and this in your html:

```
<div class="card-header">
<img src="yourpic.jpg" style=" width:100%; height:100%;">
</div>
```

Your image will now expand to your given `div` size you declared in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set your image height to 100% of your div and then use width:auto ?

`<img src="/path/to/your-image.png" style="height:100%; width:auto;" >`

Even if the height of your div changes, the image will adjust proportionally.

Also, if you want this page to load reasonably quickly, it would definitely be worth re-sizing that image.

Comment: Tried it without any effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code so this is a guess:

```
 <div MB018>
       <img src="whatever.jpg" width="10px" height="10px">
 </div>
```